# NetworkManager in text mode for Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, text-mode

How do I get wireless network when X11 is not running? In my GNOME Session, there is an icon at the top right corner of the screen, where I have configured by home wifi settings, and it connects every time I log in to X11. But how do I get the same settings without X11 running? If it's not possible, then how do I get wireless in Ubuntu Lucid text mode if I know the SSID and the WPA passphrase?

Comment: You are very unlucky - this is your 9th question and you haven't had an answer wirth accepting yet...

Comment: [See a similar question on the Ubuntu site.](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/can-i-use-networkmanager-without-a-tray-dock-bar)

Answer (score 2):

It is a while since I used wireless in Ubuntu, but ticking the box for "enable for all users" for the connection (used to) makes the machine connect before logging in.

Otherwise you could try switching to the `wicd` netwrok manager rather than the one called network manager. Wicd has a curses interface available.

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505136) is a description on the Ubuntu forums, together with what I'll take as a recommendation.

Comment: A quick follow-up: wicd didn't work out for me, sometimes it failed to connect to hidden wireless networks, and GUI integration wasn't good enough. I ended up switching back to NetworkManager, using cnetworkmanager and nmcli to drive it from the command-line.

Comment: Ticking the box for "enable for all users" worked for me. Thank you. I didn't realize this option until reading this.